# Downsampling with pandas produces NaN

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean, pandas-resample

I am downsampling data from 15 minutes scale to hourly scale with pandas resample.mean(). The result has NaN values.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaAn3.png)
[C_hourly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrMxv.png)

```
Data = Data.set_index('readable_time')
C_hourly = Data.groupby(['sensor_no'],as_index=False).resample('H').mean()
```

I wanted to have the mean of 15 minute temperature records and its corresponding sensor numbers. I am wondering if it works when I split the csv file into n files for n sensors.

Answer (score 1):

When using `pd.DataFrame.resample` a timerange is generated ranging from the smallest to the largest time entry present, the present values are aggregated on these bins. Bins without values get `NaN`. In order to avoid this behaviour use `pd.Grouper`.

This isue can be visualised using

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[1,25.3,'2023-01-16 00:08:19'],
                  [1,25.1,'2023-01-16 00:23:19'],
                  [1,25.0,'2023-01-16 02:08:19']],
                 columns = ['sensor_no','temp','readable_time'])
```

On an hourly basis the lowest entry is `2023-01-16 00:00:00` and the highest `2023-01-16 02:00:00` as such `resample('H')` will create a range index with three entries

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-16 00:00:00', '2023-01-16 01:00:00',
               '2023-01-16 02:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='readable_time', freq='H')
```

In our dataframe `df` the first two entries will correspond to the first index and the third one to the third entry. As such there will be no entry to average over for the second index leaving behind a `NaN`. Indeed

```
df.set_index('readable_time').groupby(['sensor_no'],as_index=False).resample('H').mean()
```

|  | sensor_no | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 1 | 25.2 |
| 2023-01-16 01:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2023-01-16 02:00:00 | 1 | 25 |

As mentioned in to solely aggregate on the rounded timevalue instead use a `pd.Grouper`

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='readable_time',freq='H'),'sensor_no']).mean()
```

This results in

|  |  | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 1 | 25.2 |
| 2023-01-16 02:00:00 | 1 | 25 |